# c fscanf for ints causes segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

DISCLOSURE: This is homework.

The code below is meant to read a command file formatted like:

`ADD 6 6 5`
`ADDTERM 0 1 1`
`MULTIPLY 2 40`

and call the appropriate command using the given parameters.  For some reason, while ADD and ADDTERM work as expected, I get a segfault when the multiply line is read.

```
    int arg_1 = 0, arg_2 = 0, arg_3 = 0;

    while(fscanf(commands, "%s", command) != EOF)
    {
            if(strcmp(command, "ADDTERM") == 0)
            {
                    /*The following line runs fine!*/
                    fscanf(commands, "%d %d %d",
                                    &arg_1, &arg_2, &arg_3);
                    printf("ADDTERM, Poly: %d, Coeff: %d, Exp: %d\n",
                                    arg_1, arg_2, arg_3);
                    if(polys[arg_1] == NULL)
                    {polys[arg_1] = CreatePolynomial();}
                    AddTermToPoly(polys[arg_1], arg_2, arg_3);
            }

            else if(strcmp(command, "MULTIPLY") == 0)
            {
                    /*The following line results in a segfault*/
                    fscanf(commands, "%d %d", &arg_1, &arg_2);

                    printf("MULTIPLY, Poly: %d, Multiplier: %d\n",
                                    arg_1, arg_2);
                    MultiplyPoly(polys[arg_1], arg_2);
            }

            /*...*/  
   }
```

This is also only a problem on my school's Linux server.  My home computer runs it just fine, using "gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)", whereas my school uses "gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)"

Any ideas why this would be?  Your help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact value of the `commands` string when the code runs?

Comment: commands isn't a string, but a *FILE.  Is that not how it's supposed to be?

Comment: it always helps if you can post the minimal program that will enable others to reproduce your error.

Comment: it's possible that something earlier in the program is corrupting memory, have you tried rerunning with a file that only contains the multiply line?

Comment: What is the size of the string "command"? You may have forgotten to leave a space for '\0'

Comment: jonsca, that was it. I can't believe I forgot the null! I'm utterly baffled as to why this code worked properly on my home computer though.  Do different compilers handle whitespace differently?

Comment: @user373374: There's a reason it's called "undefined behavior" :)

Comment: @user373374: where exactly your code get crashed? are you sure that the `polys` array is large enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave room for a null terminus '\0' in your string.  You were okay with ADDTERM because it has 1 less letter than MULTIPLY.